# How to match values from different array of objects based on a property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two separate arrays of objects. How can I match properties in one array of objects to another property in the second array?

I need to match the cars **use** in the `const cars` with the **searchingUse** in the `const buyers`.

```
const cars = [
{ model:convertible,
  year:2015,
  use:sports
},
{ model:wagon,
  year:2013,
  use:family
}
]

const buyers =[
{  name:John
   searchingUse: family,
   maxYear: 2014,
   maxPrice:15000

},
{  name: Mark
   searchingUse: sedan,
   maxYear: 2012,
   maxPrice:1000

}
]
```

The expected output would be a string listing all the cars that match with each buyers desired **use**

I greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get stuck, what solution did you try? What happened, what went wrong? Also, wouldn’t an Array of appropriate vehicles be more useful to allow further sorting?

Comment: Shouldn't the values of `use`, `model`, `name` and `searchingUse` be strings? And what should the expected output be *exactly* (a comparison)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
const cars = [
  { model: "convertible", year: "2015", use: "sports" },
  { model: "wagon", year: "2013", use: "family" }
];

const buyers = [
  { name: "John", searchingUse: "family", maxYear: "2014", maxPrice: "15000" },
  { name: "Mark", searchingUse: "ddd", maxYear: "2012", maxPrice: "1000" }
];

const a = buyers
  .map(buyer => ({
    [buyer.name]: cars.filter(car => car.use === buyer.searchingUse)
  }));

console.log(a);
```